# How do you punctuate this sentence?

Tags: punctuation

If a character has a lot of questions in their head, but the author only lists a few items, what is the punctuation format?

Example:

> "What happened? Where am I?" and a million other questions ran through her head.

Is this correct punctuation, or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me. Alternatives that come to mind don't really work.